# What is the probability of a given bit after a shuffle?

Tags: probability

Let $S = \{b_1, b_2 ,...,b_n\}$ be a sequence of bits of size $n$, $b_i \in \{0, 1\}$

Let $f$ be a simple shuffling algorithm (you can consider [Fisher–Yates](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array-using-fisher-yates-shuffle-algorithm/) as an example).

We have $$f(S) = S^{\prime} = \{b_1^{\prime}, b_2^{\prime} ,...,b_n^{\prime}\}$$

What is the probability that $$b_i^{\prime} = b_i ~|~ i \in [n]$$

---

**Example:**

If $[0, 1, 1, 0] \rightarrow [0, 0, 1, 1]$ ... What is the probability that the last bit "$1$" that I observe here after shuffling is true in the original sequence before shuffling?

The last bit here is just an example. It can be any bit.

Comment: Are we to assume that the random number generator called in the shuffling algorithm produces truly random numbers?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes. No dependencies and all are  i.i.d.

Comment: Is $b'$ the compliment to $b$?

Comment: @Alex no it's the bit holder at same index before and after. See the example I provided.

Comment: @Alex ops it seems the example looks like a compliment. I will make it clearer.

Comment: OK, but I still don't quite understand the last bit: you want to know the probability that the list bit of $S$ was $1$, given that it is $1$ in $S'$?

Comment: In other words, you know for sure it is $1$ is $S$?

Comment: @Alex yes. Suppose I give you the list after shuffling (swapping the indices randomly) and ask you to guess for any bit in the new list that the bit had same value (assuming you did not see the original list). What is the probably of having that right.

Comment: @Alex no you should not know how the original arrangement of the bits was before shuffling! But of course we know how many ones and zeros in total before and after as they stay the same.

Comment: So, you're given the number of $0$s and $1$s and want to know the probability that, after a fair shuffle, the last bit is $1$?

Comment: @robjohn a given bit at a given index. Not strictly the last one. It was just an example for illustration.

Comment: It seems like you're just talking about ransom permutations, then.  The particular shuffling algorithm is irrelevant.  If there are $n$ $1$-bits and $m$ $0$-bits, then the probability that a given bit is $1$ both before and after the shuffle is $\frac{n^2}{(n+m)^2}$ and for $0$-bits the probability is $\frac{m^2}{(n+m)^2}$ so the probability that the bit has the same value before and after is $\frac{n^2+m^2}{(n+m)^2}$.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @saulspatz can you extend your comment in an answer and why you add them together. I think it's very close to the answer I'm looking for but I did not get the full derivation of your formula yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are just talking about random permutations, and the particular shuffling algorithm makes no difference.  If so, then the probability that a given bit ends up in a particular position is the same for all bits.  If there are $n$ $1$-bits and $m$ $0$-bits, then the probability that the bit in a given position is $1$ after the shuffle is $\frac n{n+m}$.  On the other hand the probability that a position selected at random before the shuffle has a $1$ in it is also $\frac n{n+m}$, and since the events are independent, the probability that the position contains $1$ both before and after the shuffle is $\frac{n^2}{(n+m)^2}$.  Similarly, the probability that a random position contains $0$ both times is $\frac{m^2}{(n+m)^2}$, so the probability that it contains the same number both times is $$\frac{n^2+m^2}{(n+m)^2}$$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understood the question, but the Python code in the provided link randomly samples an integer strictly between the current bit and the last (including) for swapping, except the first swap, which happens w.p.$1$.

I think I got a solution for a simpler problem, but you should be able to extend it to yours. Let's assume the last two bits in $S$ are $11$, so after the first swap you still got $1$. You can condition on the total number of swaps with the last bit. Two first two cases are no swaps and exactly one swap. If there were no swaps, $P(S_n =1|no \ swaps)=1$ and the probability of no swaps is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. For the second case, if we don't know anything about the values of bits in the positions in $S$, let $\sigma$ be the share of $1$ in $S$, then $P(S_n =1|1 \ swap)=\sigma$, the value of bit in that specific location. The probability of exactly one swap is
\begin{align}
P(swap) &= \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{3}\times \frac{1}{n-1} + \ldots \\&= \frac{1}{n-1} \bigg(1+\frac{1}{2}+ \ldots + \frac{1}{n-2}\bigg) \approx\frac{\log(n-2)}{n-1}
\end{align}